# Cargo cannot download dependencies

Tags: ssl, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build local Rust projects with dependencies from various crates using Rust 1.35.0 on Windows 10 x64. Every time I try to run `cargo build` or `cargo run` the following error message appears.

`` error: failed to download from `https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/nom/5.0.0/download`Caused by: [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.) ``

I've tried this with several other crates apart from nom and got exactly the same error message with exception of crate name and version. Reading around pointed me to disabling my firewall, this does not work.

How can it be solved.

Comment: I see a valid certificate on my side. Are you behind a proxy or corporate network that might change that? What does your browser tell you when you visit https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/nom/5.0.0/download?

Comment: @mcarton I use my phone as a Wifi hot spot and connect my computer. Visiting the link you provided downloads nom-5.0.0.crate file. I am not behind a proxy.